# Python: How to setup a 2 phase process in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, pygame

'''I need to program a 2 phase process for a game in python.  Phase 1 leads to phase 2, then the game resets and asks again if the player would like to move to the first phase again.  I'm running into a endless loop in this example, and in my actual program it stops eventually but I can't figure out why.  Is there any way that I can set it up to where the elif clause doesn't evaluate the first iteration, but then the only evaluates on the second iteration then the program resets? Or a better way, maybe in pygame?'''

```
import sys
phase_one = 1

game_state = input("Move Forward? -- Yes or No: ")

while game_state == "Yes":

    if phase_one == 1:
        phase_one = 0

    elif phase_one == 0:
        print("Yikes!")
        phase_one = 1

else:

    if game_state == "No":

        game_state = 0
        print("Exit!")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Should edit this post and use the code {} item to format your code to make it readable.  Is game_state supposed to be an integer or a string?  You seem to be using it as both.  Endless loop makes sense.  Once in the loop, there is nothing there that would break the loop.  Is that `else:` line supposed to be at the same indent level as the `if` and `elif`?  Looks like it's at the same indent level as the `while`, which is odd.

Comment: I'm assuming your issue is that you don't what `phase_one` to toggle between 0 and 1 each iteration. If so then just add another flag for when to switch.

Comment: Check out [iminurnamez simple state machine example](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3kghhj/simple_state_machine_example/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only asks whether to move forward once, in the beginning. Then if it's the first phase it goes to the second, if it's the second it goes to the first, and if it's neither (which is impossible) it tries to check to see if it should exit (but never actually asks the user, so it would never happen anyway).

I think you were trying to write something like this:

```
phase_one = 1
game_state = "Yes"
while game_state == "Yes":
    if phase_one == 1:
        print("First phase!")
        phase_one = 0
    elif phase_one == 0:
        print("Second phase!")
        phase_one = 1
        game_state = input("Move Forward? -- Yes or No: ")
```

The way this is written makes me think of a state machine: right now we have

```
phase 1 => phase 2
phase 2 => phase 1
```

You could easily extend it with more `elif` branches, to have any of number of phases that transition to one another. I assume your ultimate goal is to have a flexible system like that. If not, and your goal is really just to have a phase one and phase two, then this is overcomplicated: all you need is

```
while True:
    print("First phase!")
    print("Second phase!")
    if input("Move Forward? -- Yes or No: ") != "Yes":
        break
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Do you have any free online resources to learn more about state machines in game programming in python?

Comment: @Adam: This guy answered your question.  You can say Thank You by clicking the Accept button (below the up/downvote buttons).  This will also prevent others from coming here thinking your question hasn't been answered yet.